# Fix text to bottom of last page in pdf using pdfmake

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdfmake

For a project im making offer and invoice pdf's on the fly using pdfmake in javascript. I would like to attach the last textblock containing the signature fields to the bottom of the last page.

My pdf docDefinition is build like this:

```js
return {
                content: [
                    getOfferLogo(), //Get the logo or empty string
                    getHeading(), //get the customer and business data (adress etc)
                    //the above is always the same
                    getText(), //get the textblock, created by user and always different
                    getSpecifics(), //get a table of payment specifications
                    getSignature() //get last textblock contaning signature fields etc, always the same
                ],
                styles: {
                    subheader: {
                        fontSize: 15,
                        bold: true,
                        alignment: 'center'
                    }
                },
                defaultStyle: {
                    columnGap: 20,
                    fontSize: 12
                }
            };
```

How can i attach the last textblock i get from calling getSignature() to the bottom of the last page of the pdf?

Comment: I've opened a [similar issue](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/479) in the project repository.

Answer (score 5):

```
var docDefinition = {
    content: content,
    footer: function(currentPage, pageCount) {                 
        if (currentPage == pageCount)
            return "Your footer goes here";
    },
}
```